# WordPress Sub Category Archive, Show Extra Empty Page Number in Pagination

Tags: wp-query, pagination

This my code for sub category archive page:

```
                <?php
                // the query
                $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                    'category__and' => array( 2 ),
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 12,
                    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
                ));
                ?>                      
                <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?> 
                    //Contents Here//

               <?php endwhile; ?><?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?><?php endif; ?>
```

And this is my pagination code:

```
            <?php global $wp_query; if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>  
            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">                                 
                <div class="mt-40 mb-60">
                    <?php mytheme_pagination(); ?>
                </div>                      
            </div>  
            <?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT:
Here is mytheme_pagination code:

```
function mytheme_pagination() {

global $wp_query;

if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 ) return; 

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

$pages = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'type'  => 'array',
        'prev_text' => __( '<i class="flaticon-left-arrow"></i>', 'mytheme' ),
        'next_text' => __( '<i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>', 'mytheme' ),
        
    ) );
    if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
        echo '<div class="pagination-wrap"><ul class="pagination">';
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                echo "<li>$page</li>";
        }
       echo '</ul></div>';
        }
}
```

Now I have 1 empty extra page number in pagination of my archive page.

For example I have only 3 pages of contents by I can See a number 4 link in pagination numbers who open's an empty page without any posts in there.

PS: There is not any problem with Category Archive page and it's only appears in SUB-Category archive page.

Can you help me please?

Comment: What is your `mytheme_pagination` code? And, how exactly you are targeting sub-category archive?

Comment: Edited the original post please check. I targeting category archive by page. like this: category-english.php (example of my sub-cat archive page)

Comment: In your query arguments, try setting `'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

Comment: Tested again, Not worked